# Registering multiple copies of a widget

Tags: widgets

I'd like to be able to register multiple copies of the Quick Search Widget in the code below, so that I can have it multiple sidebars. The code has been taken from a plugin I've downloaded

```
function quickSearchwidgetform()

{

  include(WP_DSP_ABSPATH . 'wp_search_wiget_form.php');

}



function widget_dspquicksearch($args) {

  extract($args);

  echo $before_widget;

  echo $before_title;?>
Quick Search<?php echo $after_title;

  quickSearchwidgetform();

  echo $after_widget;

}

function dspquicksearch_init()

{

wp_register_sidebar_widget(

    'dsp_quick_search_widget',        // your unique widget id

    'Quick Search Widget',          // widget name

    'widget_dspquicksearch',  // callback function

    array(                  // options

        'description' => 'A Quick Search widget that displays dsp dating quick Search form.'

    )

);  

}

add_action("plugins_loaded", "dspquicksearch_init");
```

Now I've read in the codex that the new updated method of registering a widget, should be done by register_widget() - however, when I update the code below to use this, the widgets page in my admin screen goes completely white.

Admittedly I may be out of my depth here, but am keen to learn how to fix this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be using the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

Here is a widget shell to get you started.

```
class WPSE_Widget_Shell extends WP_Widget {

  function __construct() {
    $opts = array(
      'description' => 'Brief description; shows on the backend'
    );
    parent::WP_Widget(
      'widget-id',
      'Widget Name', // shows on the backend
      $opts
    );
  }

  function form($instance) {
    echo 'backend widget form (optional if you have not user configurable options)';
  }

  function update($new_instance,$old_instance) {
    // Process backend form data
    // optional if you don't have a 'form' method
  }

  function widget($args,$instance) {
    echo 'Front end widget display';
  }

}
function register_my_widgets() {
  register_widget('WPSE_Widget_Shell');
}
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_widgets');
```

You are [`extend`ing](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) the widget class at [`wp-includes/widgets.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/widgets.php#L24) so it is good to keep an eye on the parent class. You can use the [default widgets](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/default-widgets.php) as patterns.